# Showing every user its simple specific content. e.g. a secret username and password

Tags: security, profile

How can i create a simple page to show every user a specific secret content?

I know we can show an article to a 'group' of users, but i want a simple way to show a content to single 'user'

For example every user has a special credit card and i want to show them their related credit card number and a secret password.
Is it possible with a module/plugin/...?

Comment: I hope this example is just that and you are not actually going to store credit card numbers…

Comment: No, it was just an example. I'll never store such important info ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be possible with some custom code which can be added in the article itself.

Since creating different articles for different user is not a feasible solution.

There is a [plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/5051) which allows you to add custom code anywhere you want.

Using this plugin you can add code in article which fetches the user specific details and display them.

Answer (score 4):

If you've got documents you want to show to each user, you can use RS Files, which lets you set up a briefcase to each user. But as far as showing them data, you might want to use community builder. I believe you can make custom fields that do NOT show to other users.

You could also try [JoomProfile](http://www.function90.com/products/joom-profile.html). I suspect you could pay the dev to create a module that would then pull from the special fields. That way you'd literally only have to publish ONE module and won't have to put extra code on the articles (or put the actual user data in the article). You'd just publish the module and THAT users info would appear in the module. It's really a better way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the PHP proficiency to write a simple plugin, there is a tutorial about [Creating a profile plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin) that would allow that secret data to be stored indirectly with the user profile itself.  From there, it would appear on the Profile page, as well as being available to 3rd party extensions that allow PHP code within an article.